# Segmentation fault in copying head of linked list

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have one dimensional array of pointers that I use it to store the heads of linked lists. I declare it and fill with these statements

```
struct node { long int val; struct node *next; };   //Our node structure
struct node **pointArray;
pointArray =  malloc(size_Of_array * sizeof(struct node *));
for (z =0; z<sizeof(pointArray); z++)
    pointArray[z] = NULL;
/*
do something else 
...
...
*/
while(numRead <= bytesPerThread)    //loop1
{
    m = read(fd, buff, sizeof(buff));
    numRead += m;
    if (m < 0)
        handle_error("Read error\n");
    else
    {
        for (i=0; i< m; i++)    //loop2
        {

            if (buff[i] == '#')
                while(buff[i] != '\n')
                {
                    i++;
                    continue;
                }
            else //else 2
            {
                if(buff[i] !=' ' && buff[i]!='\n' && buff[i] !='\t')
                {   temp[a] = buff[i];
                    a++;
                }
                else //else 1
                {   Node = atoi(temp);
                    a = 0;
                    for (x=0; x< 15; x++)
                        temp[x] = '\0';
                    if ((buff[i] == ' ' || buff[i] == '\t') && curruntNode == -1)//just for first time
                    {
                        head = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                        head->val = Node;   //create first node, i.e. head
                        head->next = NULL;
                        current = head; //Set current node to head
                pthread_mutex_lock(&myLock);
                        pointArray[Node] = head;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&myLock);
                        curruntNode = Node;
                    } else
                    if (buff[i] == '\n')
                    {
                        temp2 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                        temp2->val = Node;
                        temp2->next = NULL;
                        current->next = temp2;
                        current = temp2;
                    } else
                    if ((buff[i] == '\t' || buff[i] ==' ') && curruntNode != Node)
{head = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
head->val = Node;   //create first node, i.e. head
head->next = NULL;
current = head; //Set current node to head
pthread_mutex_lock(&myLock);
if (pointArray[Node] == NULL)
{
pointArray[Node] = head;}
else
{
current = pointArray[Node];
while (current->next != NULL)
{
    current = current->next;
}
current->next = head;
current = head;
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&myLock);
curruntNode = Node;}
```

Then I declare pointers to search in each linked list

```
for (j = NodesToSeek; j < NodesPerThread; j++)
{printf("hee");
    if (pointArray[j] == NULL)
        {printf("Null");continue;}
    else
    {
        firstNode = pointArray[j];
printf("1node %ld",firstNode->val);
        firstNode = firstNode ->next;
        while (firstNode != NULL)
        {
            move = firstNode;
            while (move != NULL)
            {
                comparedNode = pointArray[firstNode->val];
                comparedNode = comparedNode->next;
                while (comparedNode != NULL)
                {
                    if (comparedNode->val == move->val)
                    {
                pthread_mutex_lock(&myLock);
                        tringles++;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&myLock);
                    }
                    comparedNode = comparedNode->next;
                }//end while
                move = move->next;
            }//end while
            firstNode = firstNode->next;
        }//end while
    }//end else
}//en
```

The problem occurs in this statement

```
comparedNode = comparedNode->next;
```

This pointer remains null
Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Comment: These don't make sense: `head->val = Node;`, `pointArray[Node] == NULL`, etc.  Where/what is the definition of `Node`?

Comment: it's int. I have number of nodes each one has adjacency list, so I need to refer to the node number as index of one dimensional array

Answer (score 0):

```
pointArray =  malloc(size_Of_array * sizeof(struct node *));
for (z =0; z<sizeof(pointArray); z++)
    pointArray[z] = NULL;
```

sizeof(pointArray) returns the size of pointer in bytes in your example, not the number of elements in the array. If size_Of_array < sizeof(pointArray) then some of the array is not initialized making the following code pretty dangerous.

```
// It's possible pointArray[Node] is not initialized here
if (pointArray[Node] == NULL) 
{
    pointArray[Node] = head;
}
else 
{
...
```

You already know the size of array, so just use that for the loop.

```
pointArray =  malloc(size_Of_array * sizeof(struct node *));
for (z =0; z<size_Of_array; z++)
    pointArray[z] = NULL;
```

Comment: I used `size_Of_array` but the problem still happens

Comment: Is Node between 0 and size_Of_array

Comment: Yes, It's bounded. I'm confused, Is the declaration of one dimensional pointers array is correct?

Comment: I used eclipse debugger. I saw that `pointArray[0]` has a full linked list as I want but when I want to see other value like `pointArray[10]` I can't see it        I mean when I point to it with mouse it has arrow under this arrow one value which is `pointArray[0]`

Comment: I am guessing that the array is not populated correctly then.

Comment: I added the code that fills the array. The file stores in this way                            0\t1\n0\t5\n1\t2\n1\t5                                                                                                                                                              and so on.

Comment: I am not even going to look at that. I don't know what problem you are attempting solve. The code is not complete and its formatted poorly. I would recommend shrinking your problem down. Start with reading your data into your data structure. Make sure that works before moving on.